PHP + Imagick - how to convert Magick Vector Graphics (MVG) output to SVG?
I'm using the Imagick extension to draw line art illustrations and saw that the ImagickDraw::setVectorGraphics method can be used to output images as a vector artwork file rather than pixel data. However, this method outputs vector graphics in the Magick Vector Graphics (MVG) format when what I really want is an SVG so that I can view the vector art directly and can print it at any size.
Since Imagick can import and parse SVG data and convert it to MVG I had (naïvely) assumed that it might be possible to go the other way and convert the data from MVG to SVG, but I cannot find any documentation relating to this. As the file formats are substantially different, is there a way to easily convert MVGs to SVGs using Imagick or with a 3rd party library?
Thank you in advance for any help or advice.

Have you found a solution? I'm having similar issues.

No solution as yet. I ended up using the SimpleXMLElement extension in PHP and writing my own routines to manually generate the SVG tags (the results are identical to the ImageMagick output and did not require much coding). It should be possible to write a script to convert the MVG data into SVG format - the data in MVG to draw curves contains values very similar to how the data looks in SVG, for example, and each drawing operation is nested inside a set of "tags" (sort of).

Just to add, you could also ask about this on the ImageMagick GitHub.

I see we are more or less at the same point... ImageMagick is a bit weird sometimes and the documentation of the PHP binding clearly lacks. Anyway, I asked a slightly different question on the GitHub forum.

Just to add that from what I saw, the output of getVectorGraphics is not event an MVG file but something that looks like magick-script.

I've just checked the output and you're correct. If I look at the polygon and curve definitions in the data they are still close to what the SVG data would look like, so I think it should be possible to write a script to convert the drawing operations. The color definitions are different, although it seems that the hex values are just repeated twice (#FF66CC gets converted to #FFFF6666CCCC).

Apparently ImageMagick SVG drawing code is riddled with bugs for a long time (see the aformentionned discussion on ImageMagick GitHub). So your approach is probably the best.

By the way, I went to use ImageMagick because we use a library which is able to export to SVG but is not ported to PHP8. The library in question is pear/Image_Canvas. I opened PR to port it to PHP8 but the community is not super dynamic.

Why does the code not run in PHP8? Are you able to fix these problems or do you want me to take a look?

I know how to port it (it's not too complicated but it requires to port another package pear/Image_Color and also to modernize the test infrastructure). The PR that is open is a first step (I have other branches ready). The problem is that nobody answers on GitHub or on the pear ML. So maybe you can just leave a comment on the issue(s) to motivate them. I don't want to bother you with that of course.

If you know what changes need to be made, it would probably easier to just create a PR with all of the changes and make their job easy. And, even if they don't want to update the code, other people can see what changes need to be made to get the code to work. There seem to be so many PHP extensions and libraries that have not been updated for years (and years). I ended up spending maybe 3 weeks writing a Bézier curve drawing tool for GD because there is no hope of GD ever having one. But the tool is now available in an open source library, so others can use it if they want.

My approach was to make several small PR to lower friction and describe those steps on the PEAR ML but I never got an answer.
PEAR seems quite stuck nowadays. I was thinking about publishing my fork of the packages in question.

I think that would be a good idea, if only because of how much time people waste trying to find a solution to a problem that someone else has already solved :/ That is what GitHub is there for and why people make their source code available to the community. If someone no longer has time to update their software, they should let other people help them.

Note that I was talking about publishing them on composer. It's a last resort solution since it will increase fragmentation. I think I will do that by the end of the year (2024) if I have no news since we want to switch to PHP8 by that time.
